# Creating a simple table cell in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a simple table cell in Qt. So I have written the following code

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTableView>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

     QTableView *view = new QTableView;
     QStringListModel *model;
     view->setModel(model);
     view->show();
     model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("ID"));
     model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Name"));
     model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("City"));
     model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Country"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

But in the file mainwindow.cpp I am getting the error that "model not declared in this scope .
Its not able to do include the QSqlQueryModel header in the include part of mainwindow.cpp.

Can anyone point me where I am doing wrong ?

Thanks and Regards,
Sid

Comment: you didn't initialize model (which results in undefined behavior)

Comment: Can you please guide me on how actually we initialize model ? Thank you for your reply

Comment: I am not able to understand why its not able to do #include <QSqlQueryModel> .  Please help me regarding this... Thanks

Comment: You should read some tutorial about pointer and memory allocation. The problem is here `QStringListModel *model;`, You have a pointer to QStringListModel but with undefined value in it (that's why undefined behavior). You should at least allocate memory with `new` keyword.

Comment: I have initialized it with                                QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel ;    But Still i am getting that model is out of scope :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want multi dimensional table, but QStringListModel is one dimensional, so you can try this code. I think, that it works as you want, you get headers and you can setdata in the model in future

```
     QTableView *view = new QTableView;
      QStandardItemModel *mod = new QStandardItemModel;
      QStandardItem *it = new QStandardItem(QObject::tr("ID"));
      mod->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,it);
      QStandardItem *it1 = new QStandardItem(QObject::tr("Name"));
      mod->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1,it1);
  QStandardItem *it2 = new QStandardItem(QObject::tr("City"));
  mod->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2,it2);
  QStandardItem *it3 = new QStandardItem(QObject::tr("Country"));
  mod->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3,it3);
//and so on
      view->setModel(mod);
      view->show();
```

On the future. If you write QStandardItemModel *mod and after this you write mod->setHorizontalHeaderItem() your programm will crash, because you use bad pointer. You should allocate memory before using

Comment: Yes the code worked for me. Now I am able to create a multidimentional table :)